# Rails Ajax Partial in Popover: jQuery changes disappear when popover is reopened; changes only show on page reload

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a partial I am loading into to the data content for a popover. In the popover, I have a ajax delete action for a list element in the partial that re-renders the new updated partial. However,  when the popover is closed and re-opened, the jQuery changes made by the delete action disappear, and the partial looks as though the delete never happened. Why?

My action:

```
def destroy
  @notification = Notification.find(params[:id])
  @notification.destroy
  @notification.save

  @notifications = current_user.notifications
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render template: "notifications/destroy", :layout => false }
  end
end
```

My `destroy.js.erb`:

```
$('div#notifications-list').html($("<%= j render partial: 'notifications/notifications', locals: { notifications: @notifications } %>"))
```

The popover is called when this link is clicked; this forwards to the action `index`:

```
<li><%= link_to current_user.notifications.where(read: false).count.to_s, notifications_path, :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-flag notifications", :title => 'Notifications', "data-content" => "#{render   partial: 'notifications/notifications', locals: { notifications: current_user.notifications }}" , rel:   'popover', 'data-toggle'=>"popover", id: 'notifications', remote: true %>
</li>
```

`index` action:

```
def index
  @notifications = current_user.notifications

  @notifications.each do |notification|
    notification.update_attribute(:read, true)
  end

  @unread_count = @notifications.where(read: false).count

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { }
  end
end
```

`index.js.erb`:

```
$('#notifications').text('<%= j @unread_count.to_s %>');
```

And the popover is called in a .js file in the asset pipeline, here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a#notifications").popover({ 
    trigger: 'click',
      'container': "body",
      'placement': "bottom",
    html: true}).on("show.bs.popover", function(){ $(this).data("bs.popover").tip().css("max-width",   "300px"); 
  });
});
```

The development log says the destroy.js.erb is rendered fine, same with the index action. But for whatever reason, until the page reload the jQuery that was done in the delete action doesn't show.I've tried many things but I really can't figure out why this isn't working. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and have posted it here in case anyone has a similar problem. Just had to replace the div with the updated @notifications from the index action in `index.js.erb`:

```
$('div#notifications-list').html($("<%= j render partial: 'notifications/notifications', locals: { notifications: @notifications } %>"))
```